# How to use Google Cloud Video Intelligence Celebrity Recognition?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, video-intelligence-api

I have been using Google Cloud Video Intelligence Api happily and succesfully until this point. However, now if I am not mistaken, I noticed that Celebrity API is only open to approved selected media companies. Amazon Rekognition provides this support to public. This is quite unbelievable. How can this kind of service be a private service on such a public cloud service such as Google's ?

Does anyone know how to use Celebrity Recognition API from Google Cloud ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is about a vendor's policies which is off topic on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your question why Celebrity recognition is not made publicly available, there are legal reasons that Google may be dealing with. This type of technology is powerful and in the wrong hands could cause serious issues for all parties involved.

See the “Restricted access feature” note in Google’s documentation [1].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/celebrity-recognition

Comment: What about Amazon, Amazon Rekognition celebrity recognition is publicly available. This does not make sense.